# DB Query not running as wanted

Tags: sql, oracle, common-table-expression

My goal is to choose the highest record(By SALE) from table partition by company(CNAME) and delete other records.

```
create table Tn(cname varchar(30), sale int);
```

Table Values:

```
 CNAME          SALE
 1. Apple   4000
 2. Apple   5000
 3. Apple   4200 
 4. Samsung 3800
 5. Samsung 3900
 6. Samsung 3000
 7. Samsung 3200
 8. Nokia   800
 9. Nokia   2000
 10. Xiaomi 1100
 11. Xiaomi 700
 12. Lenovo 600
 13. Lenovo 200
 14. Lenovo 100
```

My Code:

```
with Cte as
(
  select cname,sale, dense_rank() over(partition by cname order by sale desc)as Ranker 
  from Tn
)
delete from cte where Ranker>1

select * from Tn;
```

Now this issue is I'm getting

> ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword

this error if I don't use this `select * from Tn;`

Even if I use I see no changes in the table.

I'm  Oracle SQL Live platform to use my query. Please suggest the issue of my query.

Please suggest any other way without using Common Table Expression.

**UPDATE**

I have tried out this also:

```
delete from tn 
where sale not in (select max(sale)as A 
                   from tn 
                   group by cname 
                   order by A desc);
```

But it is saying

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Comment: You can't delete from the result of a CTE in Oracle and the `order by` in the sub-select is useless and invalid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to delete from original table then `CTE` will not help you.

You will need something like following:

```
Delete from tn where rowid in
(Select rid from
(select cname,
        sale, 
        dense_rank() over(partition by cname order by sale desc)as Ranker, 
        rowid as rid
  from Tn) 
     where ranker > 1)
```

Cheers!!

Comment: seems it will work! I will check and come back to you...can you please tell why " delete from tn 
where sale not in (select max(sale)as A 
                   from tn 
                   group by cname 
                   order by A desc); " this query not running????? Its says right parenthesis missing but I see no issue in it

Comment: Can you try after removing order by? Like: `delete from tn where sale not in (select max(sale)as A from tn group by cname);

Comment: Also, i would suggest not to use `not in` at all as it handles nulls differently. So it is not at all recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting! I have never attempted to DELETE from a CTE. Instead, I would only insert the records I *want*.

```
;with cte as
(
    select      *
    from
    (
        select      *
                    ,DENSE_RANK() over(partition by cname order by sale)as Ranker
        from        Tn
    )_
    where       Ranker = 1
)
select * from cte;
```

Comment: Im getting this error : ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Can you please check with delete also?

Comment: A CTE is a real-time query (so it's evaluated every time you reference it), meaning it can't accommodate DELETE -- you apply your filter in the SELECT. If you want to perform DELETE as you are, you might use a temp table or a table variable. Both are wasteful -- why pull data that you'll delete in the next step? Again, apply your filter in the SELECT.

I might have missed something. Are you attempting to see the TOP 1 records per CName BY Sale, or are you attempting to delete data from your underlying table?

Comment: Okay then please suggest any solution to solve the issue..deletion of other rows is a mandate

Comment: So you want to delete records from Tn, not from your CTE, correct?

Comment: Yes Yes I want to delete it from Tn

Comment: I see. The schema provided has no column guaranteed to be unique, so you run the risk of deleting more than you want. Is there more to the table that you haven't shared? Perhaps a primary or natural key?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202827/discussion-between-duncan-and-andrew-watson).